# TalenD Custom Component - UIManager

Tags: talend, custom-component, look-and-feel, uimanager

I've created a custom component that has some MSGBoxes, but I would like to use the windows look instead of the ugly TalenD one.

I'm trying to do:

```
try {
    for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swingUIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but it's not working. The only way I can get talend to show windows style is by creating a swing.properties file with:

```
# Swing Look and Feel
swing.defaultlaf=UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName
```

That however is not an ideal solution. Can anyone give any suggestions to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Found a way to solve this.

All you need is to add a tJava component to the job and add:

```
    for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    }
```

and the UIManager look will switch to Windows.

Regards

P.S. If you would like to find out about the solution in more detail, then you can refer to a blog post I've made - [here](http://www.mssolutions.com/change-look-tmsgbox-client-native-talend-studio/)